# Finding a list of integers in a list of dictionaries containing strings

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I am working on a problem for a class.  We are given a long string of DNA (AGATC...) and are expected to find a match for several Short Tandem Repeats of a small subequence like AGA appearing 10 times, GTC appearing 4 times and so on.  The CSV file containing the Short Tandem Repeats looks sort of like this with the header row at the top:

`name, AGA, GTCC, ATTT`

`Ted, 4, 5, 9`

`Bill, 3, 2, 8`

Depending on the file I use, there can be more or fewer individual repeats to look for `(3 or 8)`.  I have distilled the matching Short Tandem Repeats found in the long String down to a list of integers stored in a list variable.  I get this from a text file (the string of DNA) read into memory and then analyzed using another file read into memory, the CSV file I just mentioned.  What I want to do is locate the presence of the list of integers (representing the number of times each Short Tandem Repeat appears in the long string of DNA) in the CSV file which I have also stored into a variable as a list of dictionaries (using `Dictreader`) like
`[{'name': 'Ted', 'AGA' : '4', 'GTCC' : '5', 'ATTT' : '9'}, {'name': 'Ted', 'AGA' : '3', 'AGA' : '2', 'GTCC' : '8'}]`.

How can I find a list of integers like `[4, 5, 9]` inside my list of dictionaries matching Ted's Short Tandem Repeats and then print out Ted's name as well?  Please help.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5DCS50+pset+6+DNA) is a link for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple operation indeed reading from the csv except the header and appeding it to a list.

```
import csv

value = []
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(data)
    for row in data:
        # print(row)
        value.append(row)
print(value[0])
print(value[1])
```

### Output:

```
['Ted', ' 4', ' 5', ' 9']
['Bill', ' 3', ' 2', ' 8']
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting but that really doesn't answer my question.  I have already done the above steps.